# Closing InAppBrowser when "Done" button is clicked

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

In my ionic+cordova app, I have a link to a local mp3 file that I would like to play within the InAppBrowser. When I click on it, everything is ok and it starts playing:

[image]

However, once I hit that "Done" button on the top left, I get this screen:

[image]

How can I get the window to close when I hit the "Done" button? Here is the code I am using:

```
window.open('audio/sample.mp3', 'location=no');
```

Comment: What is the plugin name you are using for this ?

Comment: It's `org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser`

Comment: Am not sure if the InAppBrowser plugin is designed to playback audio. You may have better chances opening a dummy HTML page with your sample.mp3 in it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
var yourWindow = window.open('audio/sample.mp3', 'location=no');
```

when it dones:

```
yourWindow.close();
```